# Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): TypeError: _this.$refs.editor.save is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

hey guys I'm in need of assistance , when I click my `@click="save"` button it supposed to run a save function , but instead I get the error:

*Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): TypeError: _this.$refs.editor.save is not a function*

here's the save function

```
  async save(){
        this.$refs.editor.save()   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `refs` in components, it returns an array. Maybe you should to use the first element of the array.

```js
async save(){
  this.$refs.editor[0] && this.$refs.editor[0].save()   
}
```

Be sure that your component is mounted.

Bye

Comment: yea thanks tried your idea now its saying save is not defined

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined"

Comment: Can you upload a fiddle?

Comment: async save(){
  this.$refs.editor[0].save()   
}

Comment: thank for the warning: "make sure your component is mounted" that really helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe unrelated, but ended up with same problem. This post, and @mateonunez's answer helped me fix my issues, so I will leave solution here for future readers.

I'm using jest to test if a modal appears when a button is clicked.

```
 let openModalBtn = wrapper.find('button[id="openModal"]');
 expect(openModalBtn.exists()).toBe(true); // OK
 expect(openModalBtn.is("button")).toBe(true); // OK
 await deleteBtn.trigger("click"); // BANG
```

Leading to this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: this.$refs.confirmDialogue[0].show is not a function"
```

The thing was that I was using `shallowMount`:

```
// not good
describe("some test", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {...});
  });
```

And at some point of `MyComponent`, it needs to do something like:

```
...
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      await this.$refs.confirmDialogue[0].show();
      ...
    },
```

Therefore `this.$ref` was comming as `undefined`.

Using `mount` instead:

```
// good
describe("some test", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {...});
  });
```

allowed me to click that button and find the stub within the `wrapper.html()`.